# JPA criteria count particular children from entity object hierarchy(generically)

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, criteria

I have the following situation:

```
@Entity
public class Definition {
   ...
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "productDefinition", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
   @OrderBy("name")
   private Set<Product> products = new LinkedHashSet<>();
   ....
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Product {
  ...
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Definition productDefinition;
  ...
}

@Entity
public class FancyProduct extends Product {
}

@Entity
public class PlainProduct extends Product {
}
```

In my DAO I have a generically built criteria query, over `definitions` that should extract the counts for each particular type of product (in this case `FancyProduct`, `PlainProduct` respectively). When I do a setJoin in code, like this:

```
SetJoin<T, ?> setJoin = from.joinSet(attributeName, JoinType.LEFT);
```

**UPDATE**:

I tried to extract the way the query is created. It's extracted from a broader context, so I hope it makes any sense:

```
// The result class is DefinitionDTO a DTO class 
CriteriaQuery<R> query = builder.createQuery(resultClass);
// select from - the entity class (Definition in my case)
Root<T> from = query.from(entityClass);
...
SetJoin<T, ?> setJoin = from.joinSet(attributeName, JoinType.LEFT);
// add type restriction
Class<?> manyElemTypeClass = attribute.getManyElemTypeClass();
if (manyElemTypeClass != null &&!Modifier.isAbstract(manyElemTypeClass.getModifiers()))     {
                predicates.add(builder.or(setJoin.type().in(manyElemTypeClass), setJoin.type().isNull()));
            }
            Expression<Long> count = builder.countDistinct(setJoin);
            count.alias(attributeName);
            // select count
            countSelections.add(count);
            // order by count
            orderByExpressions.add(count);
            // always restrict data based on join
            wherePath = setJoin;
  ...
```

So works when I have only one child so in this case if I need just `PlainProduct`, but as soon as I add also `FancyProduct` to the result dto, it doesn't work any longer.

The generated SQL looks like this:

```
select
    filmmateri0_
    count(distinct producepro3_.id) as col_6_0_,
from
    ProductDefinition filmmateri0_
left outer join
    (
        select
            id,
            creationDate,
            entityVersion,
            key,
            lastChangedDate,
            deleted,
            description,
            produceMaterial_id,   
            1 as clazz_ 
        from
            FancyProduct
        union
        all select
            id,
            creationDate,
            entityVersion,
            key,
            lastChangedDate,
            deleted,
            description,
            produceMaterial_id,
            2 as clazz_ 
        from
            PlainProduct
    ) producepro3_ 
        on filmmateri0_.id=producepro3_.produceMaterial_id
```

So in this case it will just count all the elements of type `Product`. Is there a way to point to the `setJoin` to `join` on a particular leaf children?

Comment: What is defference between `PlainProduct` and `FancyProduct`? Is it discriminator column?

Comment: the strategy used is different table and there is a discriminator column

Comment: Can you show us the code that builds the query? I think there should be a way to do this without having to explicitly filter on the type of the product.

Comment: @TomAnderson - I made an update, I hope it sheds some light

Comment: I see in the generated SQL Query a UNION of two tables `FancyProduct` and `PlainProduct`, each for every type you asked, so I don't really understand your problem.

Comment: @AndreiI and the generated count is on the union, meaning it will count all the children. If I put a condition as you suggested I will have the count only for that particular case only, not the count of each of the childre...